# The require method return int when it is not possible in PHP

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have following code, it saves some php code into a file, then load it, run again, sometimes the require method returns int, why does this happen？

## demo.php

```
<?php

$f = function()  use($a){
    $cachePath = '/tmp/t.php';

    $code = '<?php';
    $code .= "\n\n";
    $code .= 'return ' . var_export([], true) . ';';

    file_put_contents($cachePath, $code, LOCK_EX);

    if (file_exists($cachePath)) {
        // Sometime the following line returns int,why?
        $result = require($cachePath);
        if (!is_array($result)) {
            var_dump($result, $cachePath, file_get_contents($cachePath));
            exit("ok");
        }
        var_dump($result);
    }
};


for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
    $f();
}
```

## How to reproduce?

Run above code with two php processes by

```
php demo.php
```

Comment: Only possible explanation I can see is that perhaps some of those cache files already existed before - but with different content, than the current one you are writing. And that the old file content is somehow still "cached" on _some_ level.

Comment: The third parameter to file_put_contents has the wrong type (true). Use LOCK_EX instead.  And as you delegate to a different system, the file-system, and i/o is invovled: Race conditions. `require` or `include` return int 1 when they were successful. E.g. you required an empty file, that is valid, but it has not the return statement you expected. This is a race-condition. While you assumed the file must have been written already, it is only yet enqueued for some file-system operation. This is why you base the chaching on the actual return type (e.g. is_array() test), and let otherwise (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) include (not require) return false or int, then you know that the cache file was not yet ready. Makes little sense with the empty array naturally, but I',m sure you get the bigger picture. Also per request you normally either write the file (as you have the array already in memory) or you load it from the file, but not both. It is important that you have the procedure safe for these race-conditions / side-effects so they are more robust.

Comment: For some more background, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use -- Only you checked the file exists, it must not mean it is complete nor that it even exists the moment you require it. I hope that explains it better for the race-condition, the earlier comment is how you can prevent the issue.

Comment: @hakre What are you talking about? _"While you assumed the file must have been written already, it is only yet enqueued for some file-system operation."_ even if this would be true, the OS would handle that case transparently and you would never know.

Comment: @hakre You're misinterpreting the TOCTOU problem _"Only you checked the file exists, it must not mean it is complete nor that it even exists the moment you require it"_ is not what TOCTOU is. It's about checking whether you have the rights to access something, then swapping it out for a path you don't normally have access rights to. The only point that could be made is that after inquiring if `$path` exists, it might have been deleted when you attempt to `include` / read it.

Comment: `file_put_contents` is a synchronous operation and you can be sure the file will have been written after it returns (or, your code will behave as if it has been written), so in that sense, there isn't a race-condition going on at all.

Comment: The right approach (even though this is _extremely_ dirty to begin with) is to use a unique `$cachePath` for _each_ call.

Comment: BTW, I ran this code multiple times on my machine and it never exited with `ok` meaning it never returned something else than an array, and why would it? Either OP is using this piece of code in a HTTP environment (i.e. that is calling the script multiple times in parallel) or isn't providing the whole code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Marco: Sure, please see the link to TOCTOU only as a more well known example for a race-condition that has been documented and found its way into the encyclopedia. Perhaps you have a better link at hand to similar resources more on point for this question? Or have I missed that in your comment?

Comment: It's not clear what OP's goal is. If OP's goal is to allow multiple instances of the script to create and `include` created cache files, file locks must be used. If OP's goal is to read a file that is created by another process, an atomic file update _may_ be used (i.e. creating a file, then `rename()` it to the intended file name) [rename()s on the same file systems are considered atomic, so there will never be a file that is "half" written], or file locks can be used too.

Comment: @Marco, the above code is a simple demo,  runing it with two processes would see the exit. the cache file , t.php is built at runtime in each app instance, currently, have to this way, in my real case,  it is a big array,  I don't share it with multiple app instances via redis, because the transimit would take notable delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem isn't reproducible if there's only one executor of the script at all times.

If you're talking about running this script in parallel, well, the problem is that writing the file in exclusive mode isn't going to protect you from reading the file half-way through writing later on.

A process could be writing the file (and having the lock) but `require` doesn't adhere to that lock (file system locks are advisory, not enforced).

So the correct solution would be:

```php
<?php

$f = function()  use($a){
    $cachePath = '/tmp/t.php';

    /* Open the file for writing only. If the file does not exist, it is created.
       If it exists, it is neither truncated (as opposed to 'w'), nor the call to this function fails (as is the case with 'x').
       The file pointer is positioned on the beginning of the file. 
       This may be useful if it's desired to get an advisory lock (see flock()) before attempting to modify the file, as using 'w' could truncate the file before the lock was obtained (if truncation is desired, ftruncate() can be used after the lock is requested). */
    $fp = fopen($cachePath, "c");

    $code = '<?php';
    $code .= "\n\n";
    $code .= 'return ' . var_export([], true) . ';';
 
    // acquire exclusive lock, waits until lock is acquired
    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
    // clear the file
    ftruncate($fp, 0);
    // write the contents
    fwrite($fp, $code);

    //wrong (see my answer as to why)
    //file_put_contents($cachePath, $code, LOCK_EX);

    //not needed
    //if (file_exists($cachePath)) {
        // Lock is held during require
        $result = require($cachePath);
        if (!is_array($result)) {
            var_dump($result, $cachePath, file_get_contents($cachePath));
            exit("ok");
        }
        var_dump($result);
    //}
    // closing the file implicitly releases the lock
    fclose($fp);
};


for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
    $f();
}
```

Note that the lock isn't released and re-acquired after the write because another process could be waiting to overwrite the file.

It is not released to make sure that the same piece of code that was written is also `require`d.

However, this whole thing is questionable to begin with.

Why do you need to write a file to just later `require` it back in?

Comment: Sorry for I didn't explain my real case, I just create a simple demo to show the trouble I got. I would not write a file , then `require` it  inmediately.  write is done by another process, then there would be many read processes at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the `c` mode for fopen, It does solve my problem, without truncation, the `require` method would never return 1 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

> why does this happen？

This is standard behaviour of `require`, compare with the [docs of `include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), this behaviour is same between those two:

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.

As you can see, an integer (1) is returned on the happy path when the return is not overridden.

This makes sense for your example in so far, the file exists (therefore no fatal error), but as the file has just been created new, it might have been truncated yet only, that is, it is empty.

Therefore the return is not overridden and you can see int(1).

Another explanation is naturally you have overridden with an integer, which is also possible as multiple processes could write to the same file, but for the way you wrote the example, this is less likely. I only mention it, as this is another valid explanation.

### Include if Exists

Example how you can levitate the race-condition, as you're looking for the `$result`, not (only) if the file exists:

```php
if (($result = @include($cachePath)) &&
    is_array($result)    
) {
   # $result is array, which is required
   # ...
}
```

The thinking behind it is, that we only do little error handling, like checking the file exists as otherwise it could not be included (include() would only emit a warning and passes on with $result = false), and then if the $result loading did work with the is_array() test.

That is we design for error, but we know what we're looking for, that is $result being an array.

This is often called a transaction or transactional operation.

In this new example, we would not even enter the if-body when the $result array is empty, e.g. contains no data.

On program processing level this is likely what we're interested in and the file existing or not or being empty or not or even wrong written are all error cases it needs to "eat" and to invalidate $result.

*Define errors out of existence.*

#### Handling Parse Errors (for Include-If-Exists)

Since PHP 7.0 we can use include() and in the unfortunate event the returning include file has been half-written, we would see a PHP Parse Error which can be *caught*:

```php
# start the transaction
$result = null;
assert(
    is_string($cachePath) &&           # pathnames are strings,
    '' !== $cachePath &&               # never empty,
    false === strpos($cachePath, "\0") # and must not contain null-bytes
);
try {
    if (file_exists($cachePath)) {
        $result = include($cachePath);
    }
    # invalidate $result in case include() did technically work.
    if (!$result || !is_array($result) {
        $result = null;
    }
} catch (Throwable $t) {
    # catch all errors and exceptions,
    # the fall-through is intended to invalidate $result.
    $result = null;
} finally {
    # $result is not null, but a non-empty array if it worked.
    # $result is null, if it could not be acquired.
}
```

See [PHP try-catch-finally](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for how the throwable/exception handling works in detail, the assert() is for documenting the example for the meaning of $cachePath, the input parameter.

This second example does not use the suppression operation "@", the reason is that if it is in use as in the previous example, and the file to include would contain a real fatal error, that fatal error would be silenced. Nowadays in modern PHP this is not that much of an issue any longer, however using file_exists() + include() – while having a race-condition due to time of check vs. time of use – is safe to the non-existing file (only a warning) and fatal errors would not be hidden.

As you may already see, the more you go into the details, the harder it gets to still write the code as forward thinking as possible. We must not get lost in error handling for the error handling itself, but focus on the outcome and define those errors out of existence.

That is, include() still is leading loading the data into the memory, file_exists() is only in use to "suppress" the warning and we are aware that still though, include() may emit the warning and may return an integer, not an array.

---

And now as programming is hard: You would then perhaps wrap this in a loop, e.g. three retries. Why not a [for loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) that counts up and guards the number of retries?

Comment: Thanks for you very details explaination,  now I understand what the problem is,  The cache file is created at runtime, for my case, it doesn't change frequently. maybe  serveral times a day.  so I am gona to re-require it until the returned data is array.  do you think this is a acceptable solution?

Comment: @VidyVideni: Yes, it is viable to go by the actual data, not whether or not the file exists (only). However if you check in a loop, take care that you don't stress the system, and you don't make this loop endless. From your tests you should see the pattern, so extend it to understand the behaviour and add circuit breakers and dumpers: usleep(), number of retries before bailing out. Test with and without bailing out, your routine needs to support the happy path as well as handling the error cases, even they are unfortunate. e.g. maximum of three retries with ??? milliseconds pause.

Comment: @VidyVideni: I added two more examples to the answer which may clarify more about the pattern to include if the file exists and some more error cases and how they can be handled with PHP.

Comment: This is a horrible solution and doesn't address the underlying write-read race-condition that is happening in a parallel execution of this script. `fopen` in combination with `flock` must be used to ensure proper behaviour in that circumstance. See my answer for detail.

Comment: @Marco: It's perhaps not that visible from the answer, but in an earlier comment I already wrote that the write operation must not be done with the read operation within the process in the first place (or when done, the read must not be done as the data is already in memory). It is my understanding that the code in question is a test-script to simulate or provoke the original race-condition. And even without that, it's not "horrible" to rely on the result, not on intermediate checks. As written, YMMV.

Comment: You're looking for the race-condition in the wrong place. In a single process, there is **no** race-condition. The problem only arises if the script is executed in parallel, for which "checking the result" is not a proper solution to the problem. File locks must be used in order to avoid the race-condition, it's literally the only valid solution for that kind of problem.

Comment: Now, I'm shocked, I'm not only looking for the race-condition and therefore it must be in the wrong place? Your answer is fine @Marco, but please stop to interrupt the ongoing conversation in such an impolite manner, the OP had a real question and you may want to read about it and first clarify and then add to it, instead of just claiming someone is so wrong (on the internet). And if its just because everyone is wrong. Be part of the solution, not the problem.

Comment: And as it seems to be one of the questions you have: It depends on the file-system implementation of whether or not you can reproduce with the test-script of the OP. The hint for me was that the OP could see the integer only occasionally.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, so what do you expect me to do? I already clarified in my answer as to why. _"It depends on the file-system implementation of whether or not you can reproduce with the test-script of the OP"_ no it does not, and you are wrong for thinking that.

Comment: It's fine when you voice your opinion and say that it's wrong. And I don't say I'm totally right in every aspect of this, but this is the explanation I can offer you as a gift, be civil and accept the gesture. And never underestimate I/O, it's dirty, perhaps similar dirty as the present may look to you, but at least it's nicely wrapped up.

Comment: @hakre, thank a lot, I run it with loop, it takes about 20 micro seconds,  up to 8 loops in my  PC. this is acceptable in my case.but I am gona to accept Marco' s answer, because it  behaves better than a loop.